# Question regarding mean hitting time $E[H_j | X_0 = i ]$ of a Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value, markov-chains, conditional-expectation

Let $X_n$ be a discrete time homogeneous Markov chain and $H_j$ be the first hitting time to state $j$, that is: $H_j = min\{ n \ge 0 : X_n = j\}$.

I've seen this formula in some books and papers about the mean hitting time if $ i \neq j$ :

$$k_{ij} := E[H_j | X_0 = i ] = 1 + \sum_{m \neq j } P_{im}(1)*k_{mj}$$ where

$P_{im}(1)$ is the one step transition probability from state i to m. Unfortunately I have some problems with it. Here is my attempt:

$$
\begin{align}
E[H_j | X_0 = i] = \sum_{n = 0 }^{\infty} n * P[H_j = n | X_0 = i] \\
= \sum_{n = 
1 }^{\infty} n * P[H_j = n | X_0 = i] 
\end{align}
$$

If $n = 1$ : $P[H_j = 1 | X_0 = i] = P[X_1 = j | X_0 = i] = P_{ij}(1)$ the transition probability from i to j.

If $n \ge 2$ : $$\begin{align}P[H_j = n | X_0 = i] &= P[X_n = j, X_{n-1} \neq j , ..., X_1 \neq j | X_0 = i] \\
&= \sum_{m \neq  j} P_{im}(1)* P[X_n = j, X_{n-1} \neq j , ..., |X_1 =m, X_0 = i]  \text{ by first step analysis}\\
&= \sum_{m \neq  j} P_{im}(1)* P[X_n = j, X_{n-1} \neq j , ..., |X_1 =m] \text{ by Markov Property}\\
&= \sum_{m \neq  j} P_{im}(1)* P[X_{n-1} = j, X_{n-2} \neq j , ..., |X_0 =m] \text{ by Homogeneity of the chain} \\
&= \sum_{m \neq  j} P_{im}(1)* P[H_{n-1} = j | X_0 = m]
\end{align}$$

Doing a substitution into the expectation we have:

$$
\begin{align}
E[H_j | X_0 = i] &= \sum_{n = 1 }^{\infty} n * P[H_j = n | X_0 = i] \\
&= P_{ij}(1) + \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} n * P[H_j = n | X_0 = i]\\
&= P_{ij}(1) + \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} n * \sum_{m \neq  j} P_{im}(1)* P[H_{n-1} = j | X_0 = m]\\
&= P_{ij}(1) +\sum_{m \neq  j} P_{im}(1)\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} n * P[H_{n-1} = j | X_0 = m]\\
&= P_{ij}(1) +\sum_{m \neq  j} P_{im}(1)\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (n+1) * P[H_{n} = j | X_0 = m]\\
&=P_{ij}(1) + \sum_{m \neq  j} P_{im}(1)*[k_{mj} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}P[H_{n} = j | X_0 = m]]\\
&= P_{ij}(1) + \sum_{m \neq  j} P_{im}(1)*[k_{mj} + \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}P[H_{n} = j | X_0 = m]]\\
&= P_{ij}(1) + \sum_{m \neq  j} P_{im}(1)*[k_{mj} + P[H_j < \infty | X_0 = i]]\\
&= P_{ij}(1) + \sum_{m \neq  j} P_{im}(1)*k_{mj} + \sum_{m \neq j} P_{im}(1)*P[H_j < \infty | X_0 = i]\\
\end{align}
$$

Now If we have the extra hypothesis that: $P[H_j < \infty | X_0 = i] = 1$ then the last equation becomes:

$$\begin{align}
P_{ij}(1) + \sum_{m \neq  j} P_{im}(1)*k_{mj} + \sum_{m \neq j} P_{im}(1)*P[H_j < \infty | X_0 = i]\\
&=   P_{ij}(1) + \sum_{m \neq  j} P_{im}(1)*k_{mj} + \sum_{m \neq j} P_{im}(1)\\
&=\sum_{m \in E} P_{im}(1) + \sum_{m \neq  j} P_{im}(1)*k_{mj} \\
&= 1 +\sum_{m \neq  j} P_{im}(1)*k_{mj}
\end{align}
$$

So if we have this extra hypothesis the result would be valid. If $P[H_j < \infty | X_0 = i] < 1$ then I think the expectation would be infinite.

The problem is that I in the books that I've read this extra hypothesis is not needed, but I don't know why we can remove it.

I would really appreciate any comments or suggestions regarding this issue.

Comment: If $P[H_j < \infty \mid  X_0 = i] < 1$ then clearly $k_{ij}$ is infinite or undefined.  But it is possible to have  $k_{ij}$ infinite even when $P[H_j < \infty \mid X_0 = i] = 1$ - consider a standard 1D random walk on the integers

Comment: In this last situation the equality $E[H_j | X_0 = i ] = 1 + \sum_{m \neq j } P_{im}(1)*k_{mj}$ is still valid but equal to infinity? So the solution to the system of equations for the states doesn't exist?

Comment: In a sense you might say a solution exists but all the $k_{mj}=\infty$ when $m\not = j$

Comment: Proven here [Norris Markov Chains p.17 Theorem 1.3.5](https://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/) . Unless you could disprove him this theorem is correct , fortunately/unfortunately sometime one approach could be much easier/harder than another .